# Program started from batch file not showing GUI when executed within Java

Tags: java, batch-file, servlets

I'm new of Stack Overflow but used it so much to learn lots of things. I looked a lot for a solution of my problem and with no luck.

Anyway, the situation is:

I have a servlet that must execute a batch file to execute some operations such as start a program.

Here is the code o the servlet:

```
StringBuffer batchCommand = new StringBuffer(TerminalProperties.getRunningStorePath());
batchCommand.append("file.bat");        
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
batProcess = runtime.exec(batchCommand.toString());
```

The content of the batch file is:

```
taskkill /f /im program.exe 
cd C:\folder
start /MAX /WAIT /HIGH program.exe
```

Everything goes well when I run the batch file from a command line or with double-click. If the program.exe is running, it closes and then is restarted. When it executed from java servlet everything works but the program is started IN BACKGROUND; I need it to show the GUI.

I found some problems similar but related to task scheduler, that is not my problem.

I tried `use runas /user:Administrator program.exe` in the batch file but with no success.

Tried also to start the program with java code:

```
runtime.exec("cmd /c \"cd C:\folder & start /MAX /WAIT /HIGH program.exe\"");
```

but nothing happens...

Any ideas how can I fix it? Thanks for your time.

Comment: *I need it to show the GUI* - Where do you need it to show the GUI? As part of the servlet response?

Comment: It's about the program to be started; it has a GUI that is shown in standard situation, but not when servlet executes the bat file, that starts it in background